# Start autofs after login with systemd

Tags: linux, bash, service, systemd

I want to mount remote shares into home/user folder with systemd. The problem is that autofs attempts to mount before the above mentioned user's folder gets mounted (because it's encrypted and requires login to mount). Autofs is resistant to not available remotes, but hangs somehow if target isn't available (never again attempts mounting). So I scripted simple service to restart autofs later in process. I tried several approaches which are visible in service's script. The only viable is to have delay. This works, however only if user logs in quickly.
The script:

```
[Unit]
Description=delayedAutofs
After=network.target
RequiresMountsFor=/home/user

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "sleep 30;/bin/systemctl restart autofs.service"
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

How should it be done to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 0):

Replace line `ExecStart=/bin/bash '/usr/bin/script.sh'`

Create `script.sh` with check login in "`while`" cycle.

Comment: While I already mediated this issue by giving autofs big timeout, I wonder whether there is any neat way to do it. I considered while loop as well. While I can dislike systemd for some reasons, its event driven nature gives some possibilities. However, I could not figure out using any target to achieve needed effect.